# Proof for an Inequality

Tags: analysis, inequality

Let $e^{e^x}=\sum\limits_{n\geq0}a_nx^n$, prove that

$$a_n\geq e(\gamma\log n)^{-n}$$

for  $n\geq2$, where $\gamma$ is some constant great than $e$.

Comment: Can I ask which topics have recently been covered in your course or book?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I present three different approaches below, which may or may not appeal to you in helping you to formulate your own answer.

I think you can get this from the Taylor series at $0$ just by differentiating. If $y=y^{(0)}$ is your function and $y^{(n)}=yf_n(e^x)$, then $f_0(t)=1$, $y'=ye^x\implies f_1(t)=t$ and $y^{(n+1)}=y'f_n(e^x)+y\,e^xf_n'(e^x)$ $\implies$ $f_{n+1}(t)=f_1f_n+t\,f_n'$. Now $a_n=\frac{e\,f_n(1)}{n!}$ and $f_n(1)={}$[$B_n$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number) (as @Autolatry points out) and it shouldn't be hard to show that this sequence is increasing and has (more than) the desired growth.

---

Upon further reflection, we want to show that for $n\ge2$,
$$
a_n \ge e \left( \gamma \, \log n \right)^{-n}
$$
$$
\left( \gamma \, \log n \right)^{-n} \le \frac{a_n}{e} = \frac{B_n}{n!}
$$
$$
\gamma \, \log n \ge \left( \frac{a_n}{e} \right)^{-1/n}
= \left( \frac{n!}{B_n} \right)^{1/n}
$$
$$
\gamma \ge \sup \gamma_n \qquad\text{for}\qquad
\gamma_n = \frac1{\log n} \left( \frac{a_n}{e} \right)^{-1/n}
= \frac1{\log n}\left( \frac{n!}{B_n} \right)^{1/n}
$$

Experiment suggests that $\gamma_n$ has a global minimum at $\gamma_{37}=0.56352\,15372\,44847$, lies below its pseudonym, the Euler-Mascheroni constant, $0.57721\,56649\,01532\cdots$, for $17\le n\le 114$, and may have its global maximum at $\gamma_2=1.44269\,50408\,88963$, depending on its asymptotic value. Using a recent bound ([Berend-Tassa 2010](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number#Growth_rate)) for $B_n$ and Stirling's formula for the factorial,
$$
\gamma_n \ge 
\frac{\log(n+1)}{0.792\,n\,\log n}\Bigl( n! \Bigr)^{1/n}
\approx
\frac{\log(n+1)}{0.792\,\,n\log n}\cdot\frac{n}{e}\cdot\left(2\pi n\right)^{1/2n}
\rightarrow\frac1{0.792\,e}\approx0.46449\,,
$$
so that $\gamma=\gamma_2=\sup_{n\ge2}\gamma_n$ is in fact the best constant we can choose.

---

If we start from $y=e^{e^x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n\,x^n$ and differentiate to get $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)a_{n+1}\,x^n=y'=e^x\cdot e^{e^x}=\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}\right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n\,x^n\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{a_k}{(n-k)!}\right)x^n$, then we need to show (perhaps inductively) that the recursion $(n+1)a_{n+1}=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{a_k}{(n-k)!}$ implies the desired inequality. Now $a_0=a_1=e\cdot1$ and the first few values we care about are $a_2=e\cdot\frac22$, $a_3=e\cdot\frac56$, $a_4=e\cdot\frac{15}{24}$, which as we already know satisfy our inequality for $\gamma\ge\gamma_1$ for our inductive base ($n=2$). As inductive hypothesis (with cumulative induction), we assume the inequality for $k\le n$:
$$
a_k \ge e \left( \gamma \, \log k \right)^{-k}
$$
from which it follows by induction (and from the recursion) that
$$
\eqalign{
\frac{a_{n+1}}{e}\,\left(\gamma\log(n+1)\right)^{n+1}
&\ge \frac{\left(\gamma\log(n+1)\right)^{n+1}}{n+1} \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(\gamma\log k)^{-k}}{(n-k)!} \\
&  > \frac{\left(\gamma\log(n+1)\right)^{n+1}}{n+1} \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(\gamma\log n)^{-k}}{(n-k)!} \\
&  > \frac{\gamma\log(n+1)}{n+1} \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(\gamma\log n)^{n-k}}{(n-k)!} \\
&  > \frac{\gamma\log(n+1)}{n+1} \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(\gamma\log n)^k}{k!} \\
&  \color{red}{>} \frac{\gamma\log(n+1)}{n+1} \left(e^{\gamma\log n} - \frac{(\gamma\log n)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} \right) \\
&  = \frac{\gamma\log(n+1)}{n+1} \left(n^\gamma - \frac{(\gamma\log n)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} \right) \\
&  \color{blue}{\ge 1 \qquad\text{(what we want!)}}
}
$$
where the last inequality (in red) follows from the error theorem for Taylor series. On the subsequent line, the two terms in parentheses exhibit opposite asymptotic behavior: the former grows toward $\infty$ for all $\gamma > 1$, while the latter decays toward $0$. We need only show that the last expression is $\color{blue}{\ge1}$ for some fixed $\gamma$ and all $n\ge2$. Clearly, this is true asymptotically for all $\gamma > 1$ by the relative asymptotic growth of $\log n$ versus $n^{\gamma-1}$ (e.g. using L'Hôpital's rule). I suspect a slight modification of this argument would yield the result more elegantly.

Comment: Due to the expansion of the function  $e^{e^x}$, we know that $a_n=\frac{eB_n}{n!}$.

Comment: Yes, of course. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

\begin{equation}
e^{e^{x}} = e \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{k}B_{k}}{k!}
\end{equation}

Where $B_{k}$ is the $k$-th Bell number which is the number of partitions of a set with k entries, or the number of equivalence relations on it. Starting with $B_{0} = B_{1} = 1$, the first few Bell numbers are:
$$1, 1, 2, 5, 15, 52, 203, 877, 4140, 21147, 115975 \ldots$$